# How to group a list of list using groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a list of list that I want to group by marketName and commodityName, by listing price:
e.g. ["Terra", "Wheat", 1000.0] - "Terra" is Market name, "Wheat" is Commodity Name, 1000.0 is price

```
def marketCommodityGroup = [
                              ["Merkato", "Wheat", 1000.0],  
                              ["Shola", "Wheat", 1875.0],  
                              ["Merkato", "Barley", 5000.0],  
                              ["Merkato", "Wheat", 1000.0],  
                              ["Merkato", "Wheat", 1500.0] 
                           ]
```

I would like the output to be:

```
[
   ["Merkato": ["Wheat" : [1000.0, 1000.0, 1500.0]]],
   ["Merkato": ["Barley": [5000.0]]],
   ["Shola": ["Wheat": [1875.0]]]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers posted, I never expected i will get answers  this soon. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, here's one way of doing it.

```
def mapped = marketCommodityGroup.groupBy {
  [(it[0]) : it[1]]
}.collect { k,v ->
  def grouping = k.find { true }
  def prices = v.inject([]) { acc,val -> acc + val[2] }
  [ (grouping.key) , [ (grouping.value) : prices ] ]
}.sort { left, right ->
  right[0] <=> left[0]
}.collect {
  [(it[0]) : it[1] ]
}
```

- first `groupBy` does *exactly* what you said, it groups by the market name and commodity name
- `collect` creates the wanted structure excluding the final `k:v` association:

  - `grouping` is the only entry in the key map split so that it can be reordered to desired form
  - `prices` is done with the very handy `inject` which is Groovy's equivalent for the `fold left` operation in functional languages
- `sort` is for flipping the order as you specified - had to quess what the actual logic is so you may want to replace it
- last `collect` does the final map assignment to get the exact wanted form

Yes, it's a bit dense and magical but you can always move the closures to defs with proper, descriptive names.

Answer (score 3):

*[Edit: now returns list of maps, per original question]*

Somewhat influenced by Vamsi Krishna's answer, but with chained `withDefault` :

```
def marketCommodityGroup = [
                              ["Terra", "Wheat", 1000.0],  
                              ["Shola", "Wheat", 1875.0],  
                              ["Terra", "Barley", 5000.0],  
                              ["Terra", "Wheat", 1000.0],  
                              ["Terra", "Wheat", 1500.0] 
                           ]

def marketCommodityMap = [:].withDefault{ [:].withDefault{ [:].withDefault {[]} } }

// map looks like
// ["Terra-Wheat": ["Terra": ["Wheat": [1000.0 ...], "Barley": [5000.0] ]]]
// but we will discard the outer compound key                            
marketCommodityGroup.each { market, commodity, price ->    
    marketCommodityMap["${market}-${commodity}"][market][commodity] << price
}

def listOfMaps = marketCommodityMap.values()
println listOfMaps
```

Comment: This does not result in what is expected though. List of maps is expected, although your approach is lot cleaner. :)

Comment: Good catch and thanks... I've made edits. It took some work but I realized that a collection of maps is just an outer map without the keys.

Answer (score 3):

Another version just for fun ;-)

```
def marketCommodityGroup = [ [ "Terra", "Wheat", 1000.0  ],  
                             [ "Shola", "Wheat", 1875.0  ],  
                             [ "Terra", "Barley", 5000.0 ],  
                             [ "Terra", "Wheat", 1000.0  ],  
                             [ "Terra", "Wheat", 1500.0  ] ] 

def group( tree, data ) {
    if( data.size() > 2 ) { group( tree."${data.head()}", data.tail() ) }
    else {
        if( !tree."${data.head()}" ) tree."${data.head()}" = []
        tree."${data.head()}" << data[ -1 ]
    }
}

def grouped = { [:].withDefault{ owner.call() } }()
marketCommodityGroup.each {
    group( grouped, it )
}

assert grouped == ['Terra':['Wheat':[1000.0, 1000.0, 1500.0], 'Barley':[5000.0]],
                   'Shola':['Wheat':[1875.0]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
def marketCommodityGroup = [["Terra", "Wheat", 1000.0],  
                            ["Shola", "Wheat", 1875.0],  
                            ["Terra", "Barely", 5000.0],  
                            ["Terra", "Wheat", 1000.0],  
                            ["Terra", "Wheat", 1500.0]]


def marketMap = [:].withDefault{[:]}  
def commodityMap = [:].withDefault {[]}

marketCommodityGroup.each{ market, comm, price ->
  commodityMap[comm].add(price)
}
println("commodityMap: "+commodityMap)                            

marketCommodityGroup.each{ market, comm, price ->
  marketMap[market][comm] = commodityMap[comm]
}                            
println("MarketMap: "+marketMap)
```

Output:

```
commodityMap: [Wheat:[1000.0, 1875.0, 1000.0, 1500.0], Barely:[5000.0]]
MarketMap: [Terra:[Wheat:[1000.0, 1875.0, 1000.0, 1500.0], Barely:[5000.0]], Shola:[Wheat:[1000.0, 1875.0, 1000.0, 1500.0]]]
```

Comment: I have to say that I like your solution more, I was brute forcing mine.

Comment: But Vamsi's solution doesn't give the answer.

Comment: Ahh! I just realized that! Thanks for pointing it out Isammoc.

Answer (score 1):

```
def expected = [
   ["Terra": ["Wheat" : [1000.0, 1000.0, 1500.0]]],
   ["Terra": ["Barley": [5000.0]]],
   ["Shola": ["Wheat": [1875.0]]]
]                         

assert expected == marketCommodityGroup
                       .groupBy([{it[0]}, {it[1]}]) //Grouping based on 2 keys
                       .collectEntries{key, val-> 
                            [key, val.collectEntries{k, v -> //Collect entries
                                [k, v.collect{it[2]}.sort()]}] //Sorted price
}.inject([]){list, key, val -> //To transform result as a list
    val.each{k, v -> list << [(key): [(k): v]]}
    list
}
```

If you only need the map representation of the data then **do not** use inject, you would get:

```
[
 'Terra':['Wheat':[1000.0, 1000.0, 1500.0], 'Barley':[5000.0]], 
 'Shola':['Wheat':[1875.0]]
]
```