# Groovy/Grails : How to groupBy multiple keys combined?

Tags: grails, groovy, functional-programming

I have a list and i want to group by all three keys, i refer to [How to group a list of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332248/how-to-group-a-list-of-list-using-groovy).

```
def given  = [
  [Country:'Japan',Flag:'Yes',Event:'New Year'],
  [Country:'china',Flag:'No',Event:'Spring Festival'],
  [Country:'uk',Flag:'No',Event:'National Holiday'],
  [Country:'us',Flag:'Yes',Event:'Labour Day'],
  [Country:'us',Flag:'Yes',Event:'New Year'],
  [Country:'uk',Flag:'Yes',Event:'Memorial Day']
]
```

We can group by:

```
 def mapped = given.groupBy {
      [(it["Country"]) : it["Flag"] ] }
```

How can I group by  `[(it["Country"]) : it["Flag"] : it["Event"] ]` ?

expected results : `[['Japan':['Yes':[NewYear]]]:[['Country':'Japan', 'Flag':'Yes', 'Event':'New Year']]` , ..

Comment: what is your expected result of tripple groupby?

Comment: @droggo I have edited question with expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this is good for, I don't understand.  @dmahapatro 's solution gives a much more handlable result.  In your example you just want to have a recursive map as key for the group by.  I have my strongest doubts, that this will handle the actual grouping case well.

```
def given  = [
[Country:'Japan',Flag:'Yes',Event:'New Year'],
[Country:'china',Flag:'No',Event:'Spring Festival'],
[Country:'uk',Flag:'No',Event:'National Holiday'],
[Country:'us',Flag:'Yes',Event:'Labour Day'],
[Country:'us',Flag:'Yes',Event:'New Year'],
[Country:'uk',Flag:'Yes',Event:'Memorial Day']
]

println given.groupBy{ [(it.Country): [(it.Flag): [it.Event]]] }.inspect()
//=> [['Japan':['Yes':['New Year']]]:[['Country':'Japan', 'Flag':'Yes', 'Event':'New Year']], ...
```

Comment: No idea what it's for, but this answer is better than the one I came up with, which was `given.inject([:].withDefault{[]}) { m, v -> m.get([(v.Country):[(v.Flag):[v.Event]]]) << v ; m}`

Comment: Thank you @cfrick and tim_yates for answer its solved my problem.  I am pretty new with groovy and functional programming, I want to start with a book is there any suggestion for me on how to start?

Answer (score 2):

```
given.groupBy( { it.Country }, { it.Flag }, { it.Event } )
```

A method taking 3 closures as arguments.

Comment: Thank you for reply but I want to have something like  [['Japan':['Yes':[NewYear]]]:[['Country':'Japan', 'Flag':'Yes', 'Event':'New Year']] as an output.. sorry i didn't mention it clearly in my question.